# Area preservation when transverse intersection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems

This might be something way too trivial but I'm not seeing it yet so if you could explain to me the following I'd be thankful.

On this page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomoclinicTangle.html the property "area preservation" is used, but I don't see where this comes from.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Historical note: homoclinic tangles were discovered by Poincaré, when he was studying the 3 body problem. In that setting (Hamiltonian system), the area is preserved

Answer (score 3):

"Area preservation" is a common hypothesis for dynamical systems. In the setting of that article, it probably means that $\text{Area}(T(A)) = \text{Area}(A)$ for each Borel measurable subset $A$.

However, area preservation is by no means a necessary hypothesis for studying homoclinic connections of surface diffeomorphisms, so I don't see why it is included in that article.